# WHY is it not incrementing (Microsoft SQL)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is my function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Ref_no() 
RETURNS CHAR(20) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @reff_no CHAR(20)
    DECLARE @result CHAR(20)

   /* SET @reff_no = (SELECT MAX(refno) FROM jobOffer WHERE refno LIKE CONCAT( MONTH(getDate()), '-', SUBSTRING(YEAR(getDate()),3,2), '-%'))*/
   SET @reff_no = (SELECT MAX(refno) FROM jobOffer ) 
    IF @reff_no is null 
        SET @result = CONCAT(RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, MONTH(getDate())),2), '-', SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,YEAR(getDate())),3,2), '-', '000001')
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @reff_month CHAR(20)
            SET @reff_month = LEFT(@reff_no,2);
            Declare @month CHAR(20)
            SET @month = RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, MONTH(getDate())),2);

            DECLARE @reff_year CHAR(20)
            SET @reff_year = CONVERT(VARCHAR,SUBSTRING(@reff_no,4,2));
            Declare @year CHAR(20)
            SET @year =  SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,YEAR(getDate())),3,2);

                If ((@reff_year = @year)AND(@reff_month = @month))
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @no INT
                    SET @no = CONVERT(int,RIGHT(@reff_no,6)) + 1 
                    DECLARE @s CHAR(20)
                    SET @s = RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@no),6)
                    SET @result = CONCAT(RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, MONTH(getDate())),2), '-', SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,YEAR(getDate())),3,2), '-',@s)
                END

                ELSE 
                    SET @result = CONCAT(RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, MONTH(getDate())),2), '-', SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(getDate())),3,2), '-', '000001')

        END

RETURN @result

END
GO
```

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE jobOffer (
    id int Primary Key Identity(1,1),
    refno varchar(20),
    code int,
    Full_Name nvarchar(50),
    Passport_no nvarchar(20),
);


INSERT INTO jobOffer (refno,code,Full_Name,Passport_no)VALUES (dbo.Ref_no(),12345, 'sdf', '123ec123' );
INSERT INTO jobOffer (refno,code,Full_Name,Passport_no)VALUES (dbo.Ref_no(),12345, '', '123ec123' );
INSERT INTO jobOffer (refno,code,Full_Name,Passport_no)VALUES (dbo.Ref_no(),12345, '', '123ec123' );
INSERT INTO jobOffer (refno,code,Full_Name,Passport_no)VALUES (dbo.Ref_no(),12345, '', '123ec123' );
INSERT INTO jobOffer (refno,code,Full_Name,Passport_no)VALUES (dbo.Ref_no(),12345, '', '123ec123' );
INSERT INTO jobOffer (refno,code,Full_Name,Passport_no)VALUES (dbo.Ref_no(),12345, '', '123ec123' );
select * from jobOffer
```

But the ref_no column is not incrementing in the table y.

Comment: Using `varchar` without a size is a terrible idea.

Comment: More on topic, what happens if you execute each `INSERT` statement in it's own batch?

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee no deletes from the table, I'd make this work by storing the *date* instead and then use a combination of the date and the `id` column to generate the reference numbers on the fly:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo._jobOffer (
    id int Primary Key Identity(1,1),
    _entryDate date not null default (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
    code int, /* TODO - Nullability? */
    Full_Name nvarchar(50),
    Passport_no nvarchar(20),
);
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.jobOffer
with schemabinding
as
    select
        id,
        RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(month,_entryDate)),2) + '-' +
        RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(year,_entryDate)%100),2) + '-' +
        RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(varchar(6),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY DATEPART(month,_entryDate),
                         DATEPART(year,_entryDate)
            ORDER BY id)),6) as refno,
        code,
        Full_Name,
        Passport_no
    from
        dbo._jobOffer
go
INSERT INTO jobOffer (code,Full_Name,Passport_no)VALUES (12345, 'sdf', '123ec123' );
INSERT INTO jobOffer (code,Full_Name,Passport_no)VALUES (12345, '', '123ec123' );
INSERT INTO jobOffer (code,Full_Name,Passport_no)VALUES (12345, '', '123ec123' );
INSERT INTO jobOffer (code,Full_Name,Passport_no)VALUES (12345, '', '123ec123' );
INSERT INTO jobOffer (code,Full_Name,Passport_no)VALUES (12345, '', '123ec123' );
INSERT INTO jobOffer (code,Full_Name,Passport_no)VALUES (12345, '', '123ec123' );
select * from jobOffer
```

Note that, among other things, the above is *safe* if multiple people are inserting into the table at the same time. It also doesn't suffer from some of your logic issues (such as the fact that once you've got any entries for a December, you'll never actually find the latest issued reference number in any other months since, between all 12 digits numbers, those start `12....` will always be the `max()` compared to any others. This issue generalises to other months)

Result:

```
id          refno        code        Full_Name                                          Passport_no
----------- ------------ ----------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------
1           07-18-000001 12345       sdf                                                123ec123
2           07-18-000002 12345                                                          123ec123
3           07-18-000003 12345                                                          123ec123
4           07-18-000004 12345                                                          123ec123
5           07-18-000005 12345                                                          123ec123
6           07-18-000006 12345                                                          123ec123
```

Which is what I presume you wanted. If not, perhaps update your question with what your expected result *is*.

Comment: I'll guess right off the bat that a view cannot be used since it will return a different value for any given row if "earlier" rows have been deleted.  But only OP knows the actual and unspoken requirements.

Comment: @SMor - hence why that's the very first part of the answer "If you can guarantee no deletes from the table ..."

Answer (score 0):

The underlying issue for you is that CHAR datatypes are padded to the full size.

Your line:

```
SET @no = CONVERT(int,RIGHT(@reff_no,6)) + 1
```

Does not take that into account, so the right six characters are spaces. Add 1 and the result is always 1.

You need to modify this to:

```
SET @no = CONVERT(int,RIGHT(RTRIM(@reff_no),6)) + 1
```

That said, avoid CHARs if you can and use VARCHAR. CHAR are painful to work with as this example shows and inefficient. Converting all your CHAR to VARCHAR would resolve this issue as well.

One final suggestion, if you are going to use a function to always set the value of a column, make it the default value in the table definition and never worry about "remembering" what function to call again when inserting into that table.